# Pegar usuario do AD asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação

Galera tenho uma dúvida: como eu pego o usuário logado no windows na máquina cliente? Ele esta pegando o usuário do servidor e não da máquina cliente. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na criação do projeto, o Visual Studio oferece esta opção.

Ao criar um projeto, clique em **Change Authentication** como na tela abaixo:

[image: Novo Projeto]

Na próxima tela, clique em **Windows Authentication**:

[image: Windows Authentication]

Se o projeto já existe, modifique o seguinte no seu `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  ...
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

O nome do usuário estará, tanto em *Controllers* quanto em *Views*, dentro de `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Não é necessário fazer nenhuma mudança no iis?, a aplicação ao ser iniciada me retorna um erro 404, pedindo uma páginas login.aspx eu não possuo este arquivo no meu projeto, onde eu poderia redirecionar para ir direto aonde eu desejo?

Comment: @JeffSilva Bom, se você configurou o projeto para autenticação do Windows, não faz sentido ter tela de login. Há algum controle interno de permissões dentro do seu sistema?

Comment: já resolvi esse problema, era um redirecionamento mal colado, coloquei o redirecionamento correto, porém surge o seguinte erro: "Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance." acredito que seja a respeito do diretório onde o projeto esteja, porém ele se encontra localmente em minha maquina e eu sou administrador, então qual o motivo desse erro?

Comment: Já foi resolvido, precisei mudar a autenticação do windows no iis para enable e dar autorização ao grupo de usuarios n diretorio, obrigado cigano!