# Login com Autenticação do Windows no IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tenho uma base SqlServer 2008 em que todos os usuários podem se conectar a ela via domínio do Windows, isso funciona corretamente via SQL Management Studio.

Estou fazendo uma Aplicação C# em MVC, e queria que quando o usuário acessar o site, eu conseguisse pegar esse login e senha do windows e passar para montar a minha *Connection String*.

A minha *String* de Conexão está deste jeito:

```
conexao = new SqlConnection("Data Source=vc9;Initial Catalog=sgt;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name='Controle de Sprint';Pooling=False;User ID=dominio\\usuario;Password=senha;");
```

Assim ela funciona, porém não consigo via C# pegar o usuário do Windows do usuário que está acessando o site.

Tem como isso ser feito?

Comment: Cada usuário abre uma nova conexão em seu banco de dados? Você consegue obter o usuário que está logado, porém, a senha não tem como.

Comment: É, eu queria que cada usuário fizesse o login, pois no banco queria saber quem esta conectado. Queria que ele abrisse o site e não pedisse o usuário e senha, conectasse direto.

Comment: Não edite sua pergunta para obter mais informações. Provavelmente esse erro está na forma que configurou o seu pool. Abra uma outra pergunta informando como está configurado, explicando mais o erro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não consegue obter a senha do usuário logado, isso vai contra a política de segurança da Microsoft. Você consegue configurar uma conta do AD no `Application Pool` do `IIS` para fazer a conexão, e consegue fazer seu sistema obter o usuário logado (do Windows) em sua aplicação, sem problemas. Porém, a senha você não consegue.

Para seu sistema obter a autenticação do Windows, basta alterar seu `web.config` para isso:

```
<configuration>
  ...
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Para mais informações, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80977/20615).

E para obter o usuário logado, basta usar algo como isso:

```
var usuario = User.Identity.Name;
```

ou dependendo de onde quiser esses dados, desta forma:

```
  var usuario = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

E se não se esqueça de modificar o `IIS` para aceitar a conexão via windows.

[Neste site](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication) você encontra um tutorial de como fazer isso.

Comment: +1. boas alternativas nunca são demais.

Comment: Assim ficaria uma conexão logado apenas com um usuário né? É que tenho algumas trigger no banco que pega o @spid para gravar log e não queria mudar isso.

Comment: @lionbtt Dessa forma sim. Você consegue obter o `SPID` na aplicação, mas no BD não irá conseguir.

Answer (score 3):

primeiro você deve fazer configurar o seu IIS para realizar a autenticação utilizando Windows Authetication.

Para faze-lo no ambiente de desenvolvimento, abra o visual studio, clique com o boão direito do Mouse sobre o Projeto, escolha `Use IIS Express`, caso apareça `Use Visual Studio Developement Server` é pq já está à utilizar o `IIS Express`, então não precisa realizar nenhuma ação adicional.

Novamente utilize o Botão direito do mouse, vá em `Properties/Propriedades` e set `Anonymous Authentication` para `false` e `Windows Authentication` para `true`.

Uma vez publicada a aplicação, você precisa fazer o mesmo no IIS onde a aplicação está hospedada. para tal selecione a sua `aplicação`, então na aba `IIS` escolha `Authentication`. Novamente set `Anonymous Authentication` para `false` e `Windows Authentication` para `true`.

Uma vez feito isto, modifique a sua conexão para utilizar `Trusted_Connection` ou `Integrated Security`. não é necessario informar `id` e `password`, ele vai fazer o logon usando o usuario da rede (windows).

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDbConn1" connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
  <add name="MyDbConn2" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer essas alteração, no VS ele consegue conectar pegando meu usuário e senha do windows. Porém quando publico aparece uma caixa no Browser solicitando o usuário e senha, porém nunca da certo a conexão com o banco, sempre falha.

Comment: Dessa forma está mais claro entender, gostei da explicação. +1

Comment: @lionbtt, fez a alteração no IIS também? dá uma olhada neste [guia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx#MVCIISmgrAuthen), talvez as imagens lhe ajude a configurar.

Comment: @TobyMosque, fiz a alteração, deixei apenas o Autenticação do Windows habilitada, mas quando publico da a msg `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'`. Vi que no pool existe uma opção `Identidade`, não precisa alterar nada lá?

Comment: @lionbtt, tente utilizar a connectionstring mais basica possivel, como no exemplo acima, outra coisa, não acho uma boa ideia desligar o pool.

Comment: @lionbtt, por fim tente utilizar `connectionString` com `Trusted_Connection` ao invés de `Integrated Security`, estas duas opções deveriam ser equivalentes, mas não custa nada tentar.

Comment: @TobyMosque troquei a linha mas não consegui, sempre a mesma msg de erro. Acredito sim que é erro do IIS, porém estou com um pouco de urgencia e vou alterar o banco mesmo e logar como o Randrade informou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @lionbtt Essa mensagem de erro é porque ele está tentando acessar o banco de dados com o login 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Existe algumas opções, [como esta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx) ou [alterar o application pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @Randrade, a segunda opção foi a que deu certo pra mim, informar um usuário e senha fixo no pool. A outra mesmo o usuário logando não da certo. Obrigado Pessoal!

Comment: Pessoal, agora deu uma msg diferente ao logar, eu configurei o Web.Config para autenticação windows, criei um novo pool tudo certinho. Agora ele esta tentando pegar o nome da minha maquina e não o usuario. o nome da minha maquina é densenvolvedor1, e o usuario do windows é dominio\desenvolvedor, e esta dando essa msg de erro `Login failed for user 'dominio\desenvolvedor1$'.`